# Как записать в переменную ссылку на ячейку, а не значение VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Подскажите плз

Если я в пишу так

MyP = Range("NameRange")

у меня в переменную MyP попадает текущее значение которое записано в ячейке Range("NameRange")

А мне нужно чтобы в переменную попала ссылка на ячейку и потом я мог уже обратиться к значанию как то так

MyP2 = MyP.Value

Как это сделать?

Comment: Используйте слово [**Set**](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/set-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обратиться к диапазону, как объекту, нужно применять соответствующий оператор:

```
Set MyP = Range("NameRange")
```

Для получения значения диапазона:

```
MyPVal = Range("NameRange")
или
MyPVal = Range("NameRange").Value
```

Чтобы неприятные ситуации не портили жизнь, следует соблюдать несколько простых правил.

- Обязательно объявлять переменные с указанием их типа - `Dim MyP As Range, MyPVal As Long`
- В начале модуля, над всеми процедурами, должен быть объявлен оператор `Option Explicit`.

Очень полезная штуковина. Помогает обнаружить ошибки в коде, укажет, какие переменные не объявлены, проч. Укажет не сам, а когда пользователь запустит проверку (`Debug-Compile VBAProject`)

- При получении значения явно на это указывать - `.Value`, а не надеяться, что редактор сам все поймет правильно.

Comment: Чтобы каждый раз не вписывать в модуль строку `Option Explicit`, можно установить галочку для *"Require Variable Declaration"* в **Tools-Options-Editor** - тогда эта строка будет автоматически добавляться в каждый создаваемый модуль. Штуковина действительно очень полезная, помогает избавиться от многих ошибок и опечаток еще при написании кода, а не через несколько недель после запуска проекта